# Ubuntu 14.04 : Installing cuda 7

Tags: apt, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, cuda

I am following the procedure given here :
 http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda6.5-ubuntu

However, after I do `sudo apt-get install cuda` I get the following message:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (>= 346.46) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After I enter `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the following message:

```
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.46-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-346 (346.46-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.46-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd', which is also in package nvidia-opencl-icd-331 331.113-0ubuntu0.0.4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-opencl-icd-346_346.46-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#axzz3VF4pSfRr 
ask to remove the package.

How to do this ?

p.s. `sudo apt-get install cuda-runtime-7-0` gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working after running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean  
sudo apt-get autoclean  
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: You need to `apt-get remove` the old package v331 (or use `autoremove` like in the answer to fix after trying to install) because the installer somehow can't automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of this error by first searching for the `nvidia-opencl-icd-*` files with the following command:

```
sudo find / -name nvidia-opencl-icd-\*
```

Then I removed all the files with the following prefix

`nvidia-opencl-icd-\*`

and then ran:

`sudo apt-get -f install`